# C Programming. Printing current user

Tags: c, environment-variables

In C programming how do you get the current user and the current working directory.
I'm trying to print something like this:

```
  asmith@mycomputer:~/Desktop/testProgram:$
  (user) (computerName) (current directory)
```

I have the following code, but the username is showing as NULL. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
void prompt()
{
        printf("%s@shell:~%s$", getenv("LOGNAME"), getcwd(currentDirectory, 1024));                 
}
```

Comment: why it is not programming related.. :P

Comment: sorry it is programming related... I made a mistake adding the tag

Comment: I am on a unix environment. Actually the way I had it worked fine on the terminal. I was just showing null when compiled directly from Eclipse.

getlogin also worked fine.  Thanks all

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Note that this will work on a unix system only.
may be LOGNAME was not set as your environment variable
you can see the environment variables using the `printenv` command

```
printf("%s@shell:%s$", getenv("USER"),getenv("PWD"))
```

Also does the job.

but as mentioned you shouldn't rely on environment variables, rather use the standard c functions.If you really want to use them, first make sure it is set.

Comment: There is a huge security flaw if you usually get ur user from the environment in many cases (for example writing to /etc/shadow based on that information). Someone could just set USER=root

Answer (score 21):

Aside from the fact that you should be using the environment variable `USER` instead of `LOGNAME`, you shouldn't be using environment variables for this in the first place.  You can get the current user ID with [`getuid(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getuid) and the current effective user ID with [`geteuid(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/geteuid), and then use [`getpwuid(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwuid) to get the user name from the user ID from the passwd file:

```
struct passwd *p = getpwuid(getuid());  // Check for NULL!
printf("User name: %s\n", p->pw_name);
```

To get the current computer name, use [`gethostname(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gethostname):

```
char hostname[HOST_NAME_MAX+1];
gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname));  // Check the return value!
printf("Host name: %s\n", hostname);
```

Answer (score 5):

On unix-like systems use the function getlogin from unistd.h.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a **C** question but is more like a UNIX question. There is no portable way of getting the *username* and *current working directory* in **C** language.

However, by viewing your example, I can tell you are trying to print the current UNIX user name and current working directory.

If you need current working directory in UNIX [check *getcwd* function](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_getcwd.htm).

If you need current user name you can either call a separate **whoami** process within your **C** program, or [check the *getuid* function call](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getuid.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be platform specific, as there is no intrinsic way in the C programming language to do this.

It looks like you're on a Unix-based system, so you'll probably want to get the environment variable `USER` which is usually the logon name.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use

```
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
    system("echo %username%");    /* This is for Windows
                                   * instead use system("echo $USER"); for UNIX
                                   */
}
```